# CSS Animation Background Color Issue

Tags: html, css

Being new to CSS Animations, I have a bit of an issue that I can't figure out with the background color.

So I want there to be a delay before the animation then the background to fill from left to right which is working but the problem is the initial background color with the delay is #73A7CE and then there is a flicker to the lighter color #9BD5FF.

Is there a way to have #9BD5FF as the initial colour with the #73A7CE only coming in with the animation to create a loading type effect?

```css
html {
 box-sizing: border-box; 
 font-size: 62.5%;
 -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
    
*, *:before, *:after { box-sizing: inherit; }

body {
 background: #282828;
   color: #333;
   font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
   font-size: 1.6rem;
 line-height: 1.5;
 margin: 0;
}

.content__wrapper {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 margin-top: 4rem;
}

.promo__btn {
 align-items: center;
 animation: btn-bg-animation 5s;
 animation-delay: 4s;
 animation-timing-function: linear;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #73A7CE 50%, #9BD5FF 50%);    
    background-size: 200%;
    display: flex;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 600;
 height: 6rem;
 justify-content: center;
 padding-left: 1.8rem;
 padding-right: 1.8rem;
 width: 37.4rem;
}


@keyframes btn-bg-animation {
 from { 
  background-position: right; 
 }
 
 to { 
  background-position:left; 
 }
}
```

```html
<section class="content__wrapper">
 <div class="promo__btn">
  <span>Button</span>
 </div><!-- /.promo__btn -->
</section><!-- /.content__wrapper -->
```

If I haven't explained fully just let me know and I'll add more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 2 layers instead of one and apply animation to the `background-size` of the top layer:

```css
body {
  background: #282828;
  color: #333;
}

.promo__btn {
  animation: btn-bg-animation 5s 4s linear forwards;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(#9BD5FF, #9BD5FF), 
    #73A7CE;
  background-size: 0 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  
  display: flex;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  height: 6rem;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 27.4rem;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

@keyframes btn-bg-animation {
  to {
    background-size: 100% 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="promo__btn">
  <span>Watch Me Fade Away...</span>
</div>
```